# Table cells are out of line / sync with each other, itemize

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, formatting, align

I'm trying to have a tabular section that has bullet points next to it. There might be a
better way to go about this, but currently it seems as though the cells are out of
sync (though this might be expected from the code I'm not too sure).

Here's the MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{p{5cm} p{8cm}}

\large{1. Keyboard apple} &

\begin{itemize}
\item Trying on plates
\item Never fly pent
\item Bluo sceit tier
\end{itemize} \\

\large{2. Car in table paper} &
\begin{itemize}
\item Never always maybe
\item Circuit paper china cup
\end{itemize} \\

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Here's an image of the output :

[image]

So I'm unsure about the best way to sort this, I'm certainly not hung up on the approach
that I've taken, I just don't know any others.

Thanks

Comment: Nesting your `itemize` environments in  `enumerate` items ?

Comment: @percusse would that make them level? Or just numerate the itemized sections?

Comment: unrelated to the alignment but `\large{1. Keyboard apple}` should be `\large 1. Keyboard apple` (size commands do not take an argument)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle damn twice in one evening >.<

Comment: ah sorry didn't notice it was same OP:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ha no worries. I have it in my head that `\large{something}` is more explicit than `\large something` so did it without thinking

Comment: @baxx it is less explicit:-) `\large{something}else` looks like `something` is an argument of `\large` (which it isn't) and `else` will not be large (which it will be).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ah right, but `{\large something} else ` would work? or would it need `\large something \normalsize else`

Comment: `{\large something} else` or usually better `{\large something\par} else` work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about defining a new `I` column type?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{I}[1]{>{\leavevmode\vspace*{\dimexpr-\topsep-\baselineskip\relax}\itemize}p{#1} <{\enditemize}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}I{8cm} }
  \large{1. Keyboard apple} &
  \item Trying on plates
  \item Never fly pent
  \item Bluo sceit tier \\
  \large{2. Car in table paper} &
  \item Never always maybe
  \item Circuit paper china cup \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ah neat! didn't think (or know how!) to do that, thanks :)

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try to use \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
`! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:  not set up for use with LaTeX.`, so maybe this doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Probably your .tex file is not utf8 encoded. Which editor do you use?

Comment: Using Spacemacs (emacs)

Comment: yeah you're right - `./main.tex: LaTeX 2e document, ASCII text`, so all my files are ASCII, ace! So this solution can't work for me then?

Comment: Can you check what is its default encoding? And do you have the same problem just copying and compiling my code?

Comment: @baxx Your file is not ascii (or you would not have got that error message) not heard of spacemacs but in emacs  `C-x RET f` prompts for the encoding to save the current file,

Comment: posted the type above - just tried your code on it's own and it worked fine in a file on its own (that was the same encoding as the one that didn't work). Hmm.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did that and It has UTF 8 on the top, i got the ASCII info from running `file ./main.tex` in the shell

Comment: Not at all, just remove the line  that loads `inputenc`. But really, you should ask him to encode in utf8: all modern editors and systems understand `utf8`, and you'll have problems with accented letters from other people. What if you meet with *Gauß's lemma* or *Poincaré's lemma*?

Comment: @baxx yes I recognise file output, but file only looks at the start of the file and makes a guess. ASCII files are UTF-8 encoded (UTF8 is a full superset of ASCII) so if the file was really ascii specifying UTF-8 would be fine.

Comment: If i meet with Gauß's lemma or Poincaré's lemma UTF 8 encoding will be the least of my concerns ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known problem for itemized list in `tabular` environments; I'd avoid them to begin with, but, if you can't, here's a workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\@minipagetrue}p{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{5cm} P{8cm}}
\large 1. Keyboard apple &
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Trying on plates
  \item Never fly pent
  \item Bluo sceit tier
  \end{itemize}
\\
\large 2. Car in table paper &
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Never always maybe
  \item Circuit paper china cup
  \end{itemize}
\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Note that `\large` *doesn't* take an argument: it's a declaration that means “typeset in a larger font from now on”; here its scope is just the table cell in which it appears (it obeys groups).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. I've been trying to adapt this to another problem
(unsuccessfully) though it worked fine for this. The line
`\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\@minipagetrue}p{#1}}` sets up a new column type 'P',
this contains one argument `{P}[1]` i think? I'm not too sure what occurs after,
a minipage is involved, does it convert the right hand side to a mini page? Thanks